# $O_{K,\mathfrak{p}} = \Bbb{Z}[a]_{(p,\pi)}$ when $O_K$ is non-monogenic

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, localization, valuation-theory

This is a fun exercise I came with.

> Let $K$ be a number field, $O_K$ non-monogenic and $\mathfrak{p}$ a prime ideal above a bad prime $p$. Then how would you show that for some $a\in O_K,\pi\in \Bbb{Z}[a]$ $$O_{K,\mathfrak{p}} = \Bbb{Z}[a]_{(p,\pi)}\ ?$$

Here *bad prime* means that $O_K/(p)$ is not isomorphic to $\Bbb{F}_p[x]/(f(x))$, [for example](https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/gradnumthy/nopowerbasis.pdf) $p=2$ and $K=\Bbb{Q}[T]/(T^3-T^2-2T-8)$.

Comment: By the way can $O_K$ be non-monogenic with no bad prime ?